# Substituting key with environment variable in HOCON

Tags: scala, config, hocon, pureconfig

I am using [pureconfig](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig) to read config for my Scala application. The `application.conf` file is in HOCON format. My config file looks something like this

```
weathers {
    ${?HUMID_WEATHER_ID} {
      temperature = 10
      temperature = ${?HUMID_WEATHER_TEMPERATURR}
    }
    ${?HOT_WEATHER_ID} {
      temperature = 10
      temperature = ${?HOT_WEATHER_TEMPERATURR}
    }
}
```

`weathers` is a map whose keys should be substituted by the environment variables `HUMID_WEATHER_ID` and `HOT_WEATHER_ID`. But when I read the config I get this exception

```
 135) Unable to parse the configuration: expecting a close parentheses ')' here, not: '${'HUMID_WEATHER_ID'}'.
```

The substitutions work fine in values but not in Keys. Is this intended? Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I believe it's intended. One way is to make the keys static like `humid_wheather` and put another key inside it with the value being the env variable. This will force you to adapt slightly the app code though.

Comment: Yeah the HOCON spec effectively disallows substitutions for keys.  It's not exactly clear what the intention here is for dynamic keys like this, what higher-level problem this proposes to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use an ID for a key, might I suggest a static name such as `hot` and `humid`? Each element then has an `id` field that can be substituted.

```
weathers {
    humid {
      id = ${?HUMID_WEATHER_ID} {
      temperature = 10
      temperature = ${?HUMID_WEATHER_TEMPERATURR}
    }
    hot {
      id = ${?HOT_WEATHER_ID}
      temperature = 10
      temperature = ${?HOT_WEATHER_TEMPERATURR}
    }
}
```

Then change your code to do interpolation on the name rather than a numeric string

```
val weather = "humid"
val id = config.get(s"weathers.$weather.id")
```